# Problem with Undeploy Task in Tomcat 6

Tags: java, tomcat, ant

I am using Tomcat 6, Apache Ant 1.7.1 and JDK 1.6 on OS X Snow Leopard...

Created the following build script and supporting property files:

**(1) build.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="${project.name}" default="deploy" basedir=".">
    <property file="build.properties"/>
    <property file="admin.properties"/>

    <taskdef file="tomcatTasks.properties">
      <classpath>
        <pathelement path="${tomcat.home}/lib/catalina-ant.jar"/>
      </classpath>
    </taskdef>

    <target name="prepare">
       <mkdir dir="${webapp.build.dir}" />
       <mkdir dir="${webapp.build.dir}/WEB-INF" />
       <mkdir dir="${webapp.build.dir}/WEB-INF/lib" />
       <mkdir dir="${webapp.build.dir}/WEB-INF/classes" />
    </target>

    <target name="static" depends="prepare">
       <!-- Copy web files -->
       <copy todir="${webapp.build.dir}/">
           <fileset dir="web" />
       </copy>
       <!-- Copy webapp configuration files -->
       <copy todir="${webapp.build.dir}/WEB-INF/">
          <fileset dir="etc" />
       </copy>
       <!-- Copy properties files -->
       <copy todir="${webapp.build.dir}/WEB-INF/classes">
         <fileset dir="props" />
       </copy>
       <!-- Copy jar files -->
       <copy todir="${webapp.build.dir}/WEB-INF/lib/">
          <fileset dir="lib" />
       </copy>
    </target>

    <target name="compile" depends="static">
       <javac srcdir="src"
           destdir="${webapp.build.dir}/WEB-INF/classes/"
           deprecation="off" debug="on" optimize="off">
           <classpath>
               <!-- Include all JAR files in my local library -->
               <fileset dir="lib">
                  <include name="*.jar"/>
               </fileset>
               <!-- Include all common libraries in Tomcat -->
               <fileset dir="${tomcat.home}/lib">
                   <include name="*.jar"/>
               </fileset>
           </classpath>
       </javac>
    </target>

    <target name="deploy" depends="compile">
       <jar jarfile="${build.dir}/${webapp.name}.war" basedir="${webapp.build.dir}" />
       <!-- Copy the newly built WAR file into the deployment directory -->
       <copy file="${build.dir}/${webapp.name}.war" todir="${tomcat.deployment.dir}" />
    </target>

    <target name="clean" description="Clears all generated files, including build directories, distributables, and documentation.">
       <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="package">
       <jar jarfile="${build.dir}/${webapp.name}.war" basedir="${webapp.build.dir}" />
    </target>

    <target name="install" description="Install application in Tomcat" depends="package">
        <deploy url="${tomcat.manager.url}"
            username="${tomcat.username}"
            password="${tomcat.password}"
            path="/${webapp.name}"
            war="file:${tomcat.deployment.dir}/${webapp.name}.war"/>
    </target>

    <target name="undeploy" depends="clean" description="Remove application in Tomcat">
        <undeploy url="${tomcat.manager.url}"
              username="${tomcat.username}"
              password="${tomcat.password}"
              path="/${webapp.name}"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

**(2) admin.properties:**

```
tomcat.server=localhost
tomcat.manager.url=http://${tomcat.server}:8080/manager
tomcat.username=admin
tomcat.password=admin
```

**(3) build.properties**:

```
project.name=myproject
build.dir=./build

# Web app properties for the project
webapp.name=myproject
webapp.build.dir=${build.dir}/${webapp.name}
webapp.virtual.host=localhost
webapp.meta.dir=${webapp.build.dir}/META-INF

# Tomcat properties
tomcat.home=/Users/myuser/DevTools/Java/tomcat/apache-tomcat-6.0.20
tomcat.deployment.dir=${tomcat.home}/webapps
```

**(4) tomcatTasks.properties**:

```
# Tomcat Task Properties
deploy=org.apache.catalina.ant.DeployTask
install=org.apache.catalina.ant.InstallTask
list=org.apache.catalina.ant.ListTask
reload=org.apache.catalina.ant.ReloadTask
remove=org.apache.catalina.ant.RemoveTask
resources=org.apache.catalina.ant.ResourcesTask
roles=org.apache.catalina.ant.RolesTask
start=org.apache.catalina.ant.StartTask
stop=org.apache.catalina.ant.StopTask
undeploy=org.apache.catalina.ant.UndeployTask
```

**(5) tomcat-users.xml**:

When I run the deploy target, everything works (it places myproject.war) underneath $CATALINA_HOME/webapps...

However, when I run the undeploy target, I get the following error message:

**Problem**:

```
Buildfile: /Users/myuser/work/myproject/build.xml
Trying to override old definition of datatype resources
clean:
    [delete] Deleting directory /Users/myuser/work/myproject/build
undeploy:

BUILD FAILED
/Users/myuser/work/myproject/build.xml:83: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://localhost:8080/manager/undeploy?path=/myproject

Total time: 170 milliseconds
```

Would really appreciate it if someone could tell me what I am doing wrong...

Thank you for taking the time to read this...

Happy programming.

Answer (score 6):

It's failing because the Tomcat manager application is returning an HTTP status code 403 which means Forbidden. So access is being denied.

When I googled your question I found your [post on JavaRanch](http://www.coderanch.com/t/474812/Ant-Maven-Other-Build-Tools/Ant-with-Undeploy-Task-with) which includes your `tomcat-users.xml` file (not included here). I see that there is no user with the `manager` role which is required to run the `undeploy` task. Try adding the `manager` role to your `admin` user.

```
<role rolename="manager"/>
<user username="admin" password="admin" roles="admin,manager"/>
```

From the [Tomcat docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Configuring%20Manager%20Application%20Access):

> To enable access to the Manager web application, you must either create a new username/password combination and associate the role name manager with it, or add the manager role to some existing username/password combination.

If you're wondering why your `deploy` task seems to be working when your `undeploy` task does not, it's because the `deploy` task doesn't appear to be using the manager application for its deployment. Instead it's simply copying the `war` to the target directory.

Comment: I think you meant:

<user name="admin" password="admin" roles="admin,manager" />

Comment: Edited it to include your fix.

Answer (score 2):

Please try to add the role `manager-script` for the tomcat user you are using.

e.g.

```
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-script"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The complete user entry in tomcat 7.0 user config.

```
<role rolename="tomcat"/>
<role rolename="manager"/>
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="standard"/>
  <user username="admin" password="admin" roles="tomcat,manager,standard,manager-script,manager-gui"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

Most of time people miss the first role. stop and restart the server and you would be good.

Comment: The Tomcat docs [recommend](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html) "Users with the manager-gui role should not be granted the manager-script or manager-jmx roles."